# SonarQube TFS extension "-X" option

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, azure-pipelines-build-task

In order to get debug information when using the task "Run code analysis" (v. 4.1), is it possible to pass the "-X" option to the MSBuild scanner when setting the TFS build variable "system.debug" to "true"?

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: I hope SonarQube team will quickly release an update of the TFS extension :) In the meantime you can still pass the additional property "sonar.verbose=true" to the "Prepare Analysis Configuration" task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub issue #482 *[Automatically provide sonar.verbose=true when debug=true in TFS/VSTS](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-msbuild/issues/482)* will address this. We hope to fix this ticket in the next releases of the Scanner for MSBuild and VSTS extension (no firm date, but weeks rather than months).

Answer (score 0):

No such feature in that task, the workaround is switch task through task condition:

1. Add a Prepare Analysis Configuration task and specify additional setting (e.g. `-X`), specify **Custom conditions** in Run this task, specify `eq(variables['system.debug'], 'true')` in Custom condition
2. Add another Prepare Analysis Configuration task, specify **Custom conditions** in Run this task, specify `eq(variables['system.debug'], 'false')` in Custom condition